# How do I create a depth stencil view?

Tags: c#, directx-11, sharpdx, direct3d11, depth-testing

I am in the making of a SharpDX game and I can't figure out how to make a depth stencil view. To be fair, I also don't really know what it is. I've looked everywhere I could find online and everything I do ends up with a black screen.

Can someone tell me how to make a depth stencil view, or point me to a way that doesn't give me a black screen?

Edit:
I rewrote the code and I don't know what I did but it works now.

Comment: Have you looked at [this thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75461/how-do-i-set-up-a-depth-buffer-in-sharpdx)?

Comment: yes @ChuckWalbourn i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DepthStencilView` is effectively a pointer to a buffer/image that stores depth/stencil.

You are missing concepts here.

First, create a 2D image (texture) with `D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL` **BindFlags** and a depth/stencil image format (typically `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` is used).

Once you have a D3D11 2D Texture that can be bound as a DepthStencil output, you can create a view of the resource and then bind that to the Output Merger (`ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets (...)`).

Comment: Also ensure the resolution of the Depth/Stencil buffer is the same as your render target(s) (probably swapchain backbuffer).